# Is there a way to link a Powershell script to a custom button?

Tags: powershell, ribbon

I'm trying to run a PS script I made via custom buttons. The scripts must be loaded from Sitecore Script Library (`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library`)

The script runs perfectly if I run it from Powershell ISE, but ran from the backend, it doesn't.

```
public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Item scriptItem = _master.GetItem("{52B2BFF3-7B9B-4137-83AD-EFA6FD7ABAEC}");
                string scriptContents = scriptItem["Script"];

                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-NoProfile";
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.Start();
                    using (var sw = process.StandardInput)
                    {
                        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(scriptContents);
                        }
                    }
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert($"An error occured: {ex.Message}");
                Log.Error(ex.Message, this);

                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help on my code or alternatives is welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason your script cannot be run directly through SPE? SPE has integrations with the ribbon and other UI elements.

Comment: Check out the official documents on how to get setup with a Ribbon button. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to run your script from backend.

```
using (ScriptSession scriptSession = ScriptSessionManager.NewSession("Default", true))
{
    Item speScriptItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/path–or–id/to–spe–item");
    string script = speScriptItem["Script"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
    {
        scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(script);
    }
}
```

And if you want to extend it further, you can go with the second implementation described in this article.

https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2021/08/15/sitecore-powershell-reload-item/